# iOS 9 Automatic Update?

Tags: iphone, ios

Will iOS 9 automatically install on an iPhone? Or will it give an option to install now or later?

And if I choose later, then will it install aautomatically later, or just not suggest it again?

Comment: That question was for previous iOS Updates. This question is specific to iOS 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get a notification on your iPhone or in iTunes about iOS 9 update. It will not install automatically. You have the option to install it immediately or at a later time. If you are choosing for a later update scheme, it will show the number 1 as a badge in Settings icon on your iPhone.

Comment: Thanks! So if I choose later, it will only show the red badge and not automatically update?

Comment: @Snowbooks1419 yes. It won't automatically update.

Answer (score 0):

iPhone will only automactic download the ios not automatic-install it, so whatever what option you choose that is **"not"** or **"delay"** it will not install the ios automaticly.